# Parse.com Query Inside of Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, parse-platform

**Heres's what I'm trying to do:**

1. Get an array named `RecentPlayers` containing 4 objectId's - This is working.
2. Run a query for each of those objectId's to find their corresponding "name" (string). - Not Working.
3. Put these names into a new array, unimaginatively named `names`.  - This should work once #2 works.

**The Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function _RP(){
//Our objectId's array
var recentlyPlayed = Parse.User.current().get("RecentPlayers");
//Our names array
var names = [];
//Converting
var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
var query = new Parse.Query(User);
for (var j = 0; j < recentlyPlayed.length; j++) {
        query.equalTo("objectId", recentlyPlayed[j]);
        query.find({
            success: function(results) {
                var name = results[j].get("name");
                    console.log(name);
                names.push(name);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }
        });
    }
names = names.sort();
```

**The error:**

```
var name = results[j].get("name");
```

**Console:**

```
(4) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
query.find.succes
(anonymous function)
e 
(anonymous function)
x.each.x.forEach
c.extend.resolve
e
(anonymous function)
x.each.x.forEach
c.extend.resolve
e
(anonymous function)
x.each.x.forEach
c.extend.resolve
(anonymous function) 
e
(anonymous function)
g
c.extend.then
e
(anonymous function)
x.each.x.forEach
c.extend.resolve
j.onreadystatechange
```

I'm guessing this has to do with Parse.com's asynchronous nature.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In this case, [query.containedIn](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#containedIn) might be a more suitable constraint. Try the following code snippet:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.containedIn("objectId", recentlyPlayed);
query.find().then(function(users) {
   for(var i=0; i < users.length; i++) {
       names.push(users[i].get("name"));
   }
    names.sort();
});
```

Comment: That handled the error message, and the function appears to be working properly now, except there are no results returned.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks, eth3lbert, just needed to set** `i=0` **and** `users[i]` **in** `name.push`.

```
var query = new Parse.Query(User);
        query.containedIn("objectId", recentlyPlayed);
        query.find().then(function(users) {
            for (var i=0; i < users.length; i++) {
                names.push(users[i].get("name"));
            }   
names = names.sort();
```